# Rounding a Calculation in Java

Tags: java, rounding

This is the question:

Ernesto’s Eggs has different wholesale prices for their eggs, based upon the number sold:

0 up to but not including 4 dozen: $0.50 per dozen

4 dozen up to but not including 6 dozen: $0.45 per dozen

6 dozen up to but not including 11 dozen: $0.40 per dozen

11 dozen or more dozen: $0.35 per dozen

Extra eggs are priced at 1/12 the per dozen price.

a)Write a program that asks the user for the number of eggs, and then calculates the bill. The program output should look similar to:

Enter number of eggs: 126

Your cost is $0.40 per dozen or 0.033 per egg.

Your bill comes to $4.20

This is what I have written but I don't have the numbers rounded correctly.

```
/*
Program 1 (Ernestos Eggs)
 */
package eggs;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Laptop
 */
public class Eggs {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);


   System.out.print("Enter number of eggs: ");

   int numberofeggs=sc.nextInt();

   int numberofdozens=numberofeggs/12;

   if(numberofeggs>=0 && numberofeggs<48){

   double costpereggs= 0.50*(1/12);

   double total= (0.50*numberofdozens)+costpereggs;

   System.out.println("Your cost is $0.50 per dozen or " +costpereggs+ " per egg.");
   System.out.print("Your bill comes to $" +total); 
    }

   else if (numberofeggs>=48 && numberofeggs<72){

   double costpereggs= 0.45*(1/12);

   double total= (0.45*numberofdozens)+costpereggs;

   System.out.println("Your cost is $0.45 per dozen or  " +costpereggs+ "per egg.");
   System.out.println("Your bill comes to $" +total); 

}
   else if (numberofeggs>=72 && numberofeggs<132) {

   double costpereggs= 0.40*(1/12);

   double total= ((0.40*numberofdozens)+costpereggs);

  System.out.println("Your cost is $0.40 per dozen or " +costpereggs+ " per egg.");
  System.out.println("Your bill comes to $" +total); 


   }
   else {

  double costpereggs= 0.35*(1/12);

  double total= (0.35*numberofdozens)+costpereggs;

   System.out.println("Your cost is $0.35 per dozen or  " +costpereggs+ "per egg.");
   System.out.println("Your bill comes to $" +total); 

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding cost per egg to the total? That is irrelevant to the total.

```
double total = numberofdozens *0.35;
double costpereggs = total/numberofeggs;
```

That should be what you're looking to do.